# How to set sessionStorage in PhantomJS and CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, session-storage

The sessionStorage is not properly set using the below script. I'm trying to set the storage in a `page.evaluate` callback, but I'm not having any luck and my "complete" check endlessly loops. I've encountered the very same problem with casper, trying a similar pattern of evaluate and reload. I can't test because all ajax requests use sessionStorage to pick up the authorization JWT. I know I should have access to window in evaluate so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
var page = require("webpage").create();
var url = "http://xxxxxxxx.com";
var t0 = Date.now;
function onPageReady() {
    var t1 = Date.now;
    var elapsed = t1 - t0; 
    var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    }); 
    console.log(htmlContent);
    console.log("ELAPSED TIME: " , elapsed + "\n") ;
    phantom.exit(0);
}

page.open(url, function (status) {
    var sessionStorage = page.evaluate(function(){
      sessionStorage.setItem('authorization','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
      //window.sessionStorage.setItem('authorization','xxxxxxxxxx');
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('_USER','value');
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('USERNAME','value');
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('INTERNAL','value');
      console.log(window.sessionStorage);
      return sessionStorage;
    }); 
    t0 = Date.now;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(window.sessionStorage));
    function checkReadyState() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var readyState = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.readyState;
            }); 

            if ("complete" === readyState) {
              // checking if my ng-repeat has loaded
              if (document.getElementsByClassName('quoteTr').length > 1){ 
                  console.log("ready!")
                  onPageReady();
              } else {
                  console.log("script not complete")
                  checkReadyState();
              }   
            } else {
                checkReadyState();
            }   
        }); 
    }   

    checkReadyState();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're setting the `sessionStorage` inside of the page context (inside `page.evaluate()`), then you need to retrieve it in the page context. Although, `sessionStorage` exists outside of the page context, it is some dummy object which has no access to the page's `sessionStorage`.

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem('authorization','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
});
var authorization = page.evaluate(function(){
    sessionStorage.getItem('authorization');
});
console.log("authorization: " + authorization);
```

Since `sessionStorage` is a non-primitive object, you can't pass it outside of the page context. You can only pass representations of it, such as its key-value pairs. For the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

The same is true in CasperJS.

---

On the subject of "looping". I see three problems with your code.

First `Date.now` is a reference to a function. If you want the current time, then you have to call it as `Date.now()`.

You're not giving PhantomJS much time to do any work. You're essentially using `setTimeout()` without a second parameter which defaults to 0 which means the callback is immediately called. Try using a small timeout such as 50: `setTimeout(function(){...}, 50)`.

You're trying to access `document.getElementsByClassName('quoteTr')` outside of the page context, but `document` is only a dummy object, so it will always return an empty array no matter what happens on the page. You have to use `page.evaluate()`. CasperJS provides the `casper.exists()` function for such as case.

---

I haven't exactly understood why you need to set some `sessionStorage` values, but if you need to set them as soon as possible for the page, then you can try to employ two different strategies:

- Open the page normally, set the values to the `sessionStorage` and then load the page again so that the page's JavaScript picks up the values.
- You can try to register to `page.onLoadStarted`, `page.onNavigationRequested` or `page.onUrlChanged` events in order to set the session values as soon as possible.